# Transaction HexBytes('0x5b167dc993642d75287b01d906cdaf287efd3ee726fyg65fyihihiihy687guiyguygtf5uuttytfytfytd') is not in the chain, after 120 seconds

Tags: solidity, web3js, python, cpp-ethereum, price

import json

from web3 import Web3

## In the video, we forget to `install_solc`

## from solcx import compile_standard

from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

with open("./solidity.sol","r") as file:
abed_storage = file.read()

```
print("Installing...")
install_solc("0.8.0")

compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"Solidity.sol": {"content": abed_storage}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {
                    "*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.bytecode.sourceMap"]
                }
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.8.0",
)
```

with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
json.dump(compiled_sol, file)

```
abi= json.loads(compiled_sol["contracts"]["Solidity.sol"]["ErrorSol"]["metadata"])["output"]["abi"]
```

bytecode = compiled_sol["contracts"]["Solidity.sol"]["ErrorSol"]["evm"][
"bytecode"
]["object"]

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/c2b97c12c0ef460ca213a85f84a28e90"))
chain_id =4
my_address = "0x824DE305A3ECe4022b6F687b407Fa490f294508F"
private_key="0x50c83547ed1fd89a4dc6455769fbc686918d8b645ed62453ad6e97130393e198"

Solidity=w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_address)
transaction =Solidity.constructor().buildTransaction(
{
"chainId": chain_id,
#"gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
"from": my_address,
"nonce": nonce,
"gasPrice":500
}
)
print(transaction)

signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=private_key)
print(signed_txn)

tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)

print(tx_hash)

tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)

print(f"Done! Contract deployed to {tx_receipt.contractAddress}")

Solidity1=w3.eth.contract(address=tx_receipt.contractAddress, abi=abi)

check_transaction=Solidity1.functions.ChangName1().buildTransaction(
{
"chainId": chain_id,
"gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
"from": my_address,
"nonce": nonce + 1,
}
)
signed_greeting_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(check_transaction,private_key=private_key)

tx_greeting_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_greeting_txn.rawTransaction)

tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_greeting_hash)
print(Solidity1.functions.ChangName2().call())
print(Solidity1.functions.ChangName1().call())

Comment: This question is unreadable

Comment: Delete the question immediately. You are exposing your private key, which will cause loss of funds from the account.